# How to find UTF-8 reference of a composite unicode character

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

At work, i have this issue where i need to find the **UTF-8 reference** of a **composite unicode character**.

The character in question is a "n" with a "^" on top : n̂. This is represented in unicode by the character "n" (U+006E) followed by the circumflex accent (U+0302).

What i'm looking to find is the **single reference** of this character in UTF-8.

I've been looking all around, but i can't seem to find an answer to this. I feel stupid because it doesn't seem that finding such a simple thing would be hard.

**Edit** : So i thought that the composition of "n" and "^" could be mapped to a single UTF-8 code point (i hope i'm using the terminology right). However, you explained me that it was otherwise.
Thank you all for the help.

Loïc.

Comment: How do you know that such a Unicode glyph should exist as a single codepoint? [This rather large table](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=circumflex) doesn't include it, at least.

Comment: What exactly does "single reference" mean? You want the *n̂* character using a single Unicode code point instead of two combined? *n̂* doesn't exist as a single character in Unicode.

Comment: Hello,  what i want is the UTF-8 reference of this composite character. Am i right in thinking that for this composite unicode character (n + ^) there will be a single corresponding UTF-8 character? It is the UTF-8 reference of this character that would need.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *UTF-8 character*, and even if there were, there is no single Unicode codepoint that represents `n̂`, and even if there were, it would not be represented in UTF-8 as a single byte.

Comment: Not hard at all. If you don't mind a play on the word "reference," here it is: [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt). As you can see, it definitively does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is a **byte encoding** for a sequence of individual **Unicode codepoints**.  There is no single Unicode codepoint defined for `n̂`, not even when a Unicode string is normalized in NFC or NFKC formats.  As you have noted, `n̂` consists of codepoint `U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N` followed by codepoint `U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT`.  In UTF-8, `U+006E` is encoded as byte `0x6E`, and `U+0302` is encoded as bytes `0xCC 0x82`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the string as composed as possible, then you want it in NFC (Normalized Form Composed, see [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)). You can do this in Python [using this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/convert-between-unicode-normalization-forms-on-the-unix-command-line):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import unicodedata

for s in ['Jalapen\u0303o', 'n̂']:
  print(s)
  print(ascii(s))
  print('NFC:', ascii(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s))) 
  print('NFD:', ascii(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)))
  print('')
```

This will give you:

> Jalapeño
>
> 'Jalapen\u0303o'
>
> NFC: 'Jalape\xf1o'
>
> NFD: 'Jalapen\u0303o'
>
> n̂
>
> 'n\u0302'
>
> NFC: 'n\u0302'
>
> NFD: 'n\u0302'

As you can see, while the 'ñ' has both a composed and decomposed form, the 'n̂' does not. Its only form is decomposed, as two separate characters.

Comment: Hello Joe, thanks for the information. So this character only exists in unicode as 2 separate characters. But are these 2 composite unicode characters mapped to a single UTF-8 character? If yes, what would be the reference of this character. If they are mapped to 2 UTF-8 characters, then that's an issue for me.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UTF-8 character. UTF-8 is an encoding of one Unicode character to one-or-more bytes. The Unicode string `u'n\u0302'` encoded in UTF-8 is the byte sequence 0x6E, 0xCC, 0x82.